# How to update delaunay triangulation in 2D?

Tags: geometry, triangulation, voronoi, delaunay

What is the best way to update a current delaunay triangulation when the points moved a bit further ? Is it possible to update it, always with just flipping the sides or in some cases we need more complicated changes like remove/insert of a point ?

Comment: What didn't you like about the references I gave you in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744452/dynamic-voronoi-delaunay-triangulations-2d)?

Comment: You suggested some bunch of papers. I have read some of them but I am not going to implement something so complicated. I am looking for simple solutions even if they are not the best in the area. For example I wanted to check everytime if delaunay is valid and rebuild it only if its invalid, but even this, I think its more than O(n) for moving points. So rebuild at any time is the best option you think ?

Comment: If the points do not move much, it might be enough to check the incident triangles for the Delaunay criterion and flip them if necessary (continuing to the adjacent triangles).

Comment: Yes I thought that. I know that we have O(n) triangles, but for each triangle how many points I need to check if they are inside ? Can't that lead to a solution O(n*m) where n=#triangles, m=#points and that to lead to something Ω(n*logn) ? Is any way to check constant points for each triangle ? If you have any answer for that it would really help me reduce the times I need to rebuild the triangulation, because I will rebuild it only if triangulation is invalid. Thank you in advance !